# Excel file "NOT RESPONDING" when opened

Tags: excel, performance, delay, lag

I have an excel file that has roughly 6800 line items, I have added images/Objects to each of the line item, and saved the file.

This excel file(.xlsx) now has a size of 17.2 MB,
The problem that I am facing is after loading all images, I am unable to work with the file. Please note below what all has happened.

1. File takes about **10 minutes 8 seconds to Open**,
2. For any action further (saving, filtering, inserting a new line, deleting an old line, selecting all objects in the file) the file first goes to "Not responding" mode and then moves to active state. (this can take anywhere between 10 mins to 15 mins)

How did I add all images to rows?

1. I used a **picture lookup to achieve that**, and used the following Index and match function to lookup images to each of the row.

   `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6800,MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6800,0))`
2. I used the following code to duplicate images and data value to each image

   ```
   Sub images()
   Dim rngSel As Range
   Dim rngHdr As Range
   Dim rngCell As Range
   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim myshape As Shape



   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   If TypeOf Selection Is Range Then
   Set rngHdr = Selection.Cells(1, 1)
   Set sht = rngHdr.Parent

   ' find shape
   For Each myshape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
          If myshape.Type = msoAutoShape Or myshape.Type = msoPicture Then
                 If Intersect(myshape.TopLeftCell, rngHdr) Is Nothing Then
                Else
                        myshape.Copy
                        Exit For
                 End If
          End If
   Next myshape

   For Each rngCell In Selection.Cells
          If rngCell.Address <> rngHdr.Address Then
                 sht.Paste rngCell
                 End If
          Next rngCell
   End If

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
   ```

**Need help in making file workable.**

Comment: Excel is not the kind of program that leaves the user dealing with a completely unresponsive UI for minutes.  When it happens anyway then you'd try temporarily disable the installed anti-malware to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @HansPassant the error was due to picture lookup, there is no way to correct it in the file itself so I had to rebuild the file. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

Enter safe mode by pressing and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you start the program, or by using the `/safe` switch (`excel.exe /safe`) in Command Prompt. Click "File" > "Options" > "Add-ins". ... Then restart Excel.

Comment: it took 9 mins 48 sec to get into the file in safe mode. and in safe mode still it goes into non responding mode.  Also there were two add ins - KUTOOLS and RKTOOLS both have been disabled.

Comment: ,Thanks for your support, nut the error was due to picture lookup. when 6000 pictures were being lookedup the prg couldnt handle it. Had to rebuild the file.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file in a network folder? Try using it locally. Also try setting the calculation to manual:

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual
```

Comment: Hi @J0eBl4ck Thanks for your support, nut the error was due to picture lookup. when 6000 pictures were being lookedup the prg couldnt handle it.  Had to rebuild the file. Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked, I had to rebuild the file once again. The problem was due to multiple pics looking up the value using this formula `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6800,MATCH(Sheet1!$A$2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6800,0))`
without this the file works as it should.

Thanks for all your support.